# How did the scientists in “Armageddon” know that a nuclear explosion in the asteroid would explode into half?

Tags: armageddon

After watching [*Armageddon* (1998)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120591/), I could not understand how the NASA scientists knew that a nuclear explosion in the asteroid would split it into two halves which will take a trajectory circumventing the Earth. In reality a blast can create any amount of varying size particles. Some of which could have landed upon Earth.

Comment: Erm, because NASA is full of smart guys and supercomputers?

Comment: They read the script, and it said it would?  I thought half the nonsense in that film was that they could scan for a fault line at a million miles away, but it was barreling too fast to deflect at that range (you'd think if they could hit Russia with an ICBM they could tell it how to hit the side of Texas.  Er, a texas-sized something.)

Comment: @N.Soong Why did you remove the other part of my question where I am suggesting that deflecting the asteroid might have worked.

Comment: Actually, they didn't *know* it was going to do it. They assumed it would split in two if they could get a nuke buried deep enough on a fault line. The quote from the script reads: "*set a fire cracker off in your open palm, you get a 
third degree  burn. Close your fist, It'll do some serious 
damage. If we can get a nuke deep  in one of the asteroid's fault 
lines, she'll split in two, like a diamond.*". The rest was all hoping and praying ... one of the two worked.

Comment: @Paulster2 And the fault line was perfectly aligned with earth and the asteroid was all without turbulence and spin? And there was only one fault line?

Comment: @bubble ... it was a hope and a prayer. They didn't know it was going to do it exactly like that, but it was their only hope. What were they supposed to do, sit there and watch it hit the earth when they could try and do *something*? No, they did the something and it worked.

Comment: @Paulster2 I could not understand why deflection method was not tried. As soon as they would have heard about the asteroid they should have launched ICBMs(with required modifications). Also they could have tried second method in parallel.

Comment: @bubble; I removed it because you were providing your opinion that deflection would have worked without citing any source to support this claim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Armageddon.html) is pretty clear on this. There's a fault-line running down the middle of the meteor. Their plan is to drill into it, then, when the meteor is aligned along its axis, detonate the nuke, splitting the object into two halves. Note that the timing is key.

> **Harry :** *From all of your intel, **the deepest fault line is here. This is
>
>   my sweet spot. If I can get a clean hole in there, She'll blow in 
>   half....***
>
> **Golden** : ***...and the two pieces will slide right past us.*** You 
>   cannot shatter it.  Getting hit with 20 smaller asteroids is as 
>   bad as one big one. You have to  drill, plant the nuke,  lift 
>   off, and detonate -- all before the asteroid reaches this
>   position.
>
> (demonstrates position)
>
> *You have eight hours. Remember it. You must  detonate by this 
>   point or the two halves will hit us.*

Comment: And yes, I'm thoroughly aware how dumb this is.

Comment: But @Richard, it's not dumb, *it's in the script*! You know those four little words can solve any movie question!